# How can I find this font to download and use it?

Tags: fonts

[image]

How can I find this font to download and use it? Please I really need it. It reads "LaTeX default" and is a serif font but I cannot find it.

Comment: Do you have the pdf file? If so, you have the fonts used from Acrobat Reader > File > Properties.

Comment: This looks pretty much like good ol' Computer Modern, in different optical sizes, though. Computer Modern is the default LaTeX font.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to TeX.SX! This font is very likely Computer Modern which is the default font in TeX and is shipped with any TeX distribution. Therefore, if you want to use it with (La)TeX, there is no need to download it. If you want to use it with other software, you need to look for a TrueType or OpenType version of it that can be installed on your system.

The following will generate something that is more or less similar to the picture you posted. As you can see, no special font is loaded and the default font is used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}

\begin{document}\large

\LaTeX{} default:

\bigskip

{\centering
{\huge The Geography of Firm Births in Germany}

\textsc{David B. Audretsch}* and \textsc{Michael Fritsch}\textdagger

\textit{Wissenschaftszentrum Berlin f\"ur Socialforschung, Reichpietschufer 50, D-10784 Berlin, Germany}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help, I truly appreciate it so much!

Answer (score 1):

It seams you want to use the Computer Modern fonts outside LaTeX. You can get a version of them called the Comuter Modern Unicode, whose OTF files can be freely obtained at [CTAN folder for cm-unicode](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/cm-unicode/fonts/otf).

Comment: thank you so much! but I tried all the fonts in the list, none of them seem to resemble this font fully. I don't know why

Comment: Note that Computer Modern has different styles for different font sizes. You may need to select different fonts for the huge characters and for the smaller ones.

Comment: Try also another version of same font, called Latin Modern:
https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/lm/fonts/opentype/public/lm
for example fonts lmroman12-regular.otf, lmroman12-italic.otf, lmroman12-italic.otf

Comment: You can take a look also at https://cm-unicode.sourceforge.io/index.html

Comment: thank you so much, this was such a great help